# AnyLogic-how to randomly select agents in a particular state

Tags: random, charts, state, anylogic

I am new to AnyLogic.  I need help on the following issue.
I would like to randomly select agents in a specific state.  I would like to set up a parameter for the # of agents selected.  For example, I would like to have a random sample of 10 people in illness state.   I want to make the # of selection flexible, so I would like to use a parameter to set the # of random sample size, as well.
My vision is to have a slider to change the sample size in Main. I also set up a population called Patient and that will have a state charts includes health state and ill state.  Among those who are in ill state, I would like to sample randomly with the number given by the parameter.
Would anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make a list of individuals in the State you wanna select and then do a for loop to get the index of X individuals from that List. Where X is how many times the for loop will be executed and can be user-defined.